# Undefined body with Angular 2 post request

Tags: angular

I'm struggling a bit with angular 2 post requests, which makes me feel stupid :P I just don't seem to be able to pull the data/body through to Express/Node. Below is my angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';    

@Injectable()

export class Signup {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  submitForm(data: Object) {

    let url = 'http://localhost:8022/api/signup';
    let body = JSON.stringify({ 'foo': 'bar' });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
                    .map(res =>  res.json().data)
  }
}
```

And in express I try this:

```
  router.post('/api/signup', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('content-type', req.headers['content-type'])
    console.log('req.body', req.body)  
    res.status(200).json({message: "user created!"})
  })
```

But no body comes through, as you can see in my console:

```
content-type application/json
req.body undefined
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have to subscribe to the observable map doesn't activate it.

Comment: `.map(res =>  res.json().data).subscribe(...)` is what you're looking for. This is very different from the way promises behave and trips a lot of people up. For what it's worth, using observables for simple HTTP request is a stupid API decision.

Comment: I don think that is the issue here.. if so the request would not have been sent.OP is getting the request just not the body.It is safe to assume it has been subscribed

Comment: are you able to send request from a rest client with this body?

Comment: @suraj you're completely right.

Comment: @suaj you are right. It was my own stupidity that got in my way, as it was some middleware that messed it up. I'm still not quite sure which one it was, as I stripped it all down, and plugged it back in again, one by one. Now it's all back to where I started, and it works just fine... (Must be some differences, but I've tried to reproduce the error, without luck). Anyways, thank you both for your time and your help.